# OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR for cmake

Tags: cmake, openssl

I have built & **installed openssl 1.1.1** on my system:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1h-dev  xx XXX xxxx
```

The respective `libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so` are in `/usr/local/lib64`, headers in `/usr/local/include`. I created `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/usrlocal.conf` and added `/usr/local/lib64` there to make sure the .so are loadable.

**There is an older version (1.0.2)** in `/usr/lib64/` and `/usr/include` that i need to keep for other dependencies.

I am trying to compile OQS library (https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs) that requires

```
find_package(OpenSSL 1.1.1 REQUIRED)
```

When I try to compile the library, I get

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR: Found unsuitable version "1.0.2k", but
  required is at least "1.1.1" (found /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:443 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:450 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)
```

**I have tried setting `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`** to almost any value imaginable without any result; the error remains.

It seems to me that`cmake` only attempts to check `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` as last attempt, and that it terminates exploration for appropriate library version after finding the first suitable version...

Now the question is obvious - **how to force CMAKE to find appropriate OpenSSL version?**

### **UPDATE**

**(debunked in next update)** As @Tsyvarev suggested in the comments, setting OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR as environment variable helped. That means no `set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ...)` in CMakeLists.txt or `-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` with `cmake` command, but `export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=...` is what helped `find_package` to find the correct version.

I am still running into issues with OQS, yet this time I believe they are caused by a different issue.

```
lib/liboqs.a(fips202x4.c.o): In function `keccak_squeezeblocks4x.constprop.1':
fips202x4.c:(.text.keccak_squeezeblocks4x.constprop.1+0x6b): undefined reference to `KeccakP1600times4_PermuteAll_24rounds'
```

### **UPDATE 2**

I am actually using OQS in another CMakeLists.txt via `FetchContent` as:

```
FetchContent_Declare(liboqs 
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/onavratil-monetplus/liboqs 
    #GIT_TAG 0.2.0 
)
```

I made my custom fork and tweaked their CMakeLists.txt to export targets so that I can link appropriate dependencies to my binary in `cmake`:

```
target_link_libraries(myexecutable PUBLIC OQS::oqs)
```

The strange thing is, if I let OQS find OpenSSL on its own, I will get to the same result as in the original answer - no matter if I use -D, set() or export =.
However, if on my top level CMakeLists.txt i manually call `find_package(OpenSSL 1.1.1 REQUIRED)`, it succeeds, respective variables `OPENSSL_FOUND` etc are set properly and OQS compiles. Btw I use `cmake` version 3.17.2.

After all it was this edit (finding OPENSSL myself) that fixed the problem, this way, `-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local` works as well.

Comment: "I have tried setting OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR to almost any value imaginable" - Have you tried to set this *environment* variable to `/usr/local`? Have you cleared the CMake cache before new attempts?

Comment: Seems like setting the environmental variable indeed did the trick and pushed me a little forward. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, setting `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` as CMake variable should work too, both as `set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local")` and `-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local`.

Comment: I made some more tests. See my last update.

Comment: "I am actually using OQS in another CMakeLists.txt via FetchContent as:" - So you include OQS sources into your `CMakeLists.txt` via `add_subdirectory`. That way all variables - environment, CMake (both normal and CACHE ones) - are passed to the inner OQS `CMakeLists.txt`. So again, all ways for setting `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` variable should work. Probably, OQS redefines `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` - as a CMake one - in its `CMakeLists.txt`. If you call `find_package(OpenSSL)` manually, then futher its invocation does not search anything - they use paths which already found.

Answer (score 3):

I installed `libssl-dev` (as suggested at the bottom of the failed cmake build output) and it worked first time.

Note, that the development header packages of SSL libs are named differently on different distros. E.g. `libssl-dev`, `libssl-devel`, `openssl-dev` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the Problem when I needed openssl for an Android Project. In the scenario it helped to import openssl via gradle and then linking the fetched lib like described [here](https://gist.github.com/rhulha/3a2bce7dc3d43c4bab8a14a31feecc38)